# How to unlock account using web3js with infura?

Tags: web3js, infura

I need to unlock accounts using web3js with infura.io, but it seems that infura does not support web3.personal modules.

In this case, I think options are 1.using geth or parity for client node not infura or 2.signing accounts locally before being sent to infura.

If the option 2 is possible, how to do that?

And also, I have user account addresses, public keys, and private keys for use.

Comment: In option 2, you mean ""signing transactions", not "signing accounts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With web3.js v1.0.0-beta.34, you can use these 3 functions:

```
async sendTransaction(transaction, value = 0) {
    return await signAndSendTransaction(transaction._parent._address, transaction.encodeABI(), value);
}

async sendEtherToContract(contract, value) {
    return await signAndSendTransaction(contract._address, "", value);
}

async sendEtherToAccount(account, value) {
    return await signAndSendTransaction(account, "", value, 21000);
}
```

All of which relying on this function:

```
async function signAndSendTransaction(to, data, value, gas = 0) {
    const options = {
        to   : to,
        data : data,
        value: value,
        gas  : gas ? gas : (await web3.eth.getBlock("latest")).gasLimit;
    };
    const signedTransaction  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY);
    const transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
    return transactionReceipt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What should I do in case of calling erc20 contract methods?

Comment: @shuNjj: Something like `await sendTransaction(yourContract.methods.yourFunction(arg1, arg2), value)`. If `yourFunction` is not `payable`, then you should pass 0 for `value` (or omit this argument altogether, since it's default value is 0).

Answer (score 1):

For option 2 you need to use [`web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction) to sign your transaction locally, and then [`web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction) to publish it.

If you need to call contract methods, you need to use [`yourContract.methods.yourMethod.encodeABI`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi) in order to prepare transaction data, then sign locally and publish transaction as usual.

Comment: Thanks! What should I do in case of calling erc20 contract methods?